# Set pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex.freq with inferred_freq

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `DatetimeIndex` `tidx`

```
tidx = pd.to_datetime(['2016-07-29', '2016-08-31', '2016-09-30'])
print(tidx.freq)
print(tidx.inferred_freq)
print(tidx)

None
BM
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-29', '2016-08-31', '2016-09-30'], \
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I want the `freq` attribute to assume the `inferred_freq` attribute... so I

```
tidx.freq = tidx.inferred_freq
print(tidx)
```

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-24-b49b104fda04> in <module>()
>       1 tidx.freq = tidx.inferred_freq
> ----> 2 print(tidx)
>
> C:\Users\ssmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.pyc in __str__(self)
>      45         if compat.PY3:
>      46             return self.__unicode__()
> ---> 47         return self.__bytes__()
>      48 
>      49     def __bytes__(self):
>
> C:\Users\ssmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.pyc in __bytes__(self)
>      57 
>      58         encoding = get_option("display.encoding")
> ---> 59         return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
>      60 
>      61     def __repr__(self):
>
> C:\Users\ssmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.pyc in __unicode__(self)
>     581         klass = self.__class__.__name__
>     582         data = self._format_data()
> --> 583         attrs = self._format_attrs()
>     584         space = self._format_space()
>     585 
>
> C:\Users\ssmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.pyc in _format_attrs(self)
>     485         for attrib in self._attributes:
>     486             if attrib == 'freq':
> --> 487                 freq = self.freqstr
>     488                 if freq is not None:
>     489                     freq = "'%s'" % freq
>
> C:\Users\ssmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\base.pyc in freqstr(self)
>     223         if self.freq is None:
>     224             return None
> --> 225         return self.freq.freqstr
>     226 
>     227     @cache_readonly
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'freqstr'
> ```

---

***question***
What is the appropriate way to have my index assume it's inferred_freq?

Comment: Not sure why that doesn't work but `tidx = pd.DatetimeIndex(tidx.values, freq = tidx.inferred_freq)` does work which is a bit weird and roundabout method to do this

Comment: Directly setting the `freq` attribute to a frequency string has been fixed as of 0.23.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's unclear why the docs state you can set the `freq` attribute but then it doesn't persist but if you reconstruct the `datetimeindex` again but pass a `freq` param then it works:

```
In [56]:
tidx = pd.DatetimeIndex(tidx.values, freq = tidx.inferred_freq)
tidx

Out[56]:
DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-29', '2016-08-31', '2016-09-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use the `DatetimeIndex` constructor with your list of strings and pass `'infer'` as the `freq`:

```
In [2]: tidx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-29', '2016-08-31', '2016-09-30'], freq='infer')

In [3]: tidx
Out[3]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-29', '2016-08-31', '2016-09-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223868/2336654

I asked another question to help with this.  @root identified a function for converting frequency strings.  So this should work

```
tidx.freq = pd.tseries.frequencies.to_offset(tidx.inferred_freq)

DatetimeIndex(['2016-07-29', '2016-08-31', '2016-09-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='BM')
```