# how do I get at the pandas.offsets object given an offset string

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have an offset string `'BM'` or `'7W'`
I know the answer for `'BM'` is `pd.offsets.BMonthEnd()`
for `'7W'` is `pd.offsets.Week(7)`

Is there a generic solution in which I can pass a string and get the offset object?

Comment: for others reference http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like [`pandas.tseries.frequencies.to_offset`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tseries/frequencies.py#L390) is what's used internally to convert from offset strings to a `DateOffset` object:

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

freq = to_offset('7W')
```

You can also get it in more of a hackier way without any imports by taking the `freq` attribute of a trivial `DateTimeIndex`:

```
freq = pd.date_range('2016-03-14', periods=0, freq='7W').freq
```

Using either method:

```
print(freq)
<7 * Weeks: weekday=6>

print(type(freq))
<class 'pandas.tseries.offsets.Week'>
```

Comment: found it at the same time. deleting my answer.

Comment: you helped me answer my other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40222583/2336654