# add one value in the beginning by timestep in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe as show below,

```
  df =
   index                value
2014-05-21 10:00:00      13.0
2014-05-21 10:30:00       8.0
2014-05-21 11:00:00       9.0
2014-05-21 11:30:00       7.0
2014-05-21 12:00:00       2.0
....
```

how can I add a new value *2* in the beginning, and it would be

```
    df =
   index                value
2014-05-21 09:30:00       2.0   <- new value with new index automatically
2014-05-21 10:00:00      13.0     calculated ( 10 o'clock - 30min(timestep))
2014-05-21 10:30:00       8.0
2014-05-21 11:00:00       9.0
2014-05-21 11:30:00       7.0
2014-05-21 12:00:00       2.0
```

and

```
type(df.index) = pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex
```

I would like to add the value in the first index and the datetime would be calculate automatically by the timestep (in this case is 30 min), is there any better way to do it ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

```
df.loc[df.index[0] - pd.offsets.Minute(30), 'value'] = 2
df = df.sort_index()

df

                     value
index                     
2014-05-21 09:30:00    2.0
2014-05-21 10:00:00   13.0
2014-05-21 10:30:00    8.0
2014-05-21 11:00:00    9.0
2014-05-21 11:30:00    7.0
2014-05-21 12:00:00    2.0
```

---

### Option 2

Set the frequency of the index so you can decrement naturally.
This is from an answer by @root [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223868/2336654)

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

df.index.freq = to_offset(df.index.inferred_freq)
df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame(dict(value=[2]), [df.index[0] - 1]))

                     value
index                     
2014-05-21 09:30:00    2.0
2014-05-21 10:00:00   13.0
2014-05-21 10:30:00    8.0
2014-05-21 11:00:00    9.0
2014-05-21 11:30:00    7.0
2014-05-21 12:00:00    2.0
```

Comment: because I have some other dataframe with different timesteps (15mins, 60mins ...etw), is it possible to do it without write for example "Minute(30)" manually but calculated automatically?

Comment: you can calculate the time step with `df.index[1] - df.index[0]`

Comment: might be safer to use something like `df.index.freq = df.index.inferred_freq`

Comment: @root remember that question I asked (long time ago).  Need to convert that string to a time delta. [>>>found it<<<](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223868/2336654)

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but `df.index[0] - 1` gives me the expected result after setting freq as specified in my previous comment.

Comment: Hmm, maybe they changed it.  As of the time I asked that question, it would not work.  Testing now.

Comment: @root I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'freqstr'` which was the same error I was getting when I asked that question.  So, to use your suggestion I have to refer to **your** answer to that question `from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset; df.index.freq = to_offset(df.index.inferred_freq)`

Comment: @piRSquared: are you on 0.22.0?  Working for me on 0.22.0+.

Comment: Yes... dbl checking, yes. `0.22.0`.  `df.index.inferred_freq` is the string `'30T'`.  What do you get with `type(df.index.inferred_freq)`

Comment: Wow...This is very strange.  Calling`df.index` after setting the freq as a string gives me the `AttributeError`, but `df.index[0]` works fine and gives a `Timestamp` with the freq set appropriately.  Must be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can also using `reindex` with index `append`

```
df.reindex(pd.Index(['2014-05-21 09:30:00']).append(df.index),fill_value=2)
Out[116]: 
                     value
2014-05-21 09:30:00    2.0
2014-05-21 10:00:00   13.0
2014-05-21 10:30:00    8.0
2014-05-21 11:00:00    9.0
2014-05-21 11:30:00    7.0
2014-05-21 12:00:00    2.0
```