# ValueWarning: No frequency information was provided, so inferred frequency MS will be used

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, statsmodels

I try to fit Autoregression by sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX. But I meet a warning, then I want to set frequency information for this model.
Who used to meet it, can you help me ?

```
fit1 = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train.Demand, order=(1, 0, 0), 
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False).fit()
y_hat['AR'] = fit1.predict(start="1975-01-01", end="1975-12-01", dynamic=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot( train['Demand'], label='Train')
plt.plot(test['Demand'], label='Test')
plt.plot(y_hat_avg['AR'], label='AR')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()

C:\Users\thach.le\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels-0.8.0-py3.6-win- 
amd64.egg\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:165: ValueWarning: No frequency 
information was provided, so inferred frequency MS will be used.
% freq, ValueWarning)
```

Thanks

Comment: This question could also be tagged with [pandas], since the error only arises when sending a datetime-indexed `pandas` `DataFrame` to the `statsmodels` function.

Comment: Just shut it down

`from statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions import  ValueWarning`
`warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ValueWarning)`

Answer (score 20):

If your data is really periodic and you don't have gaps in your time series, then `pandas` can infer the frequency.

If the inferred frequency looks correct to you, you can use it by follow the answer at [Set pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex.freq with inferred_freq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222583/set-pandas-tseries-index-datetimeindex-freq-with-inferred-freq#40222783)

For example

```
train.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(train.index.values,
                               freq=train.index.inferred_freq)
fit1 = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(...)
```

But note that this can still give a `DatetimeIndex` whose frequency is `None` if your data is not truly periodic.

For example, if you have daily data and one day is missing, then the `inferred_freq` will be `None` and attempting to pass `freq="D"` will raise a `ValueError` exception. In this case, try building your `DataFrame` so that all dates are present and the values in the column(s) you're forecasting are `None` on those dates. Then you can use `missing="drop"` (or whatever) with your `ARIMA` model.

Comment: Is there a reason not to do ``train.index.freq = train.index.inferred_freq``?  - Never mind, found it in the linked question.