# How to stop python warning

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I am using the following script in the code to suppress the warning. However, I still receive a warning when calling sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX module.

```
warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore")
```

ValueWarning: No frequency information was provided, so inferred frequency MS will be used.

I just want to get rid of the warning. Is there anyway to enforce it?

Comment: try warning.filterwarnings("ignore")

Comment: did not solve the issue.

Comment: Okay, then try this https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/7044

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore the warning, try this:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=Warning)
```

But if you want to get rid of the reason of this warning, looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547245/valuewarning-no-frequency-information-was-provided-so-inferred-frequency-ms-wi#answer-50499360) might help.

Answer (score 0):

**# to suppress warnings**

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings('ignore')
```